# Is it possible to assign a class attribute to title?

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

I'm trying to figure out why a class attribute would be assigned to the title tag and whether it's good or bad practice to do so.

Comment: please re edit your topic(Title)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to assign a class attribute to title?

Yes.

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes):

> **Every** HTML element may have a class attribute specified.

---

> why a class attribute would be assigned to the title tag

Probably to allow it to be selected with JS or CSS. I can't think of a reason why anyone would want do that when they could use `document.title` or a type selector.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ah, that would make sense (allowing it to be selected with JS). Can you explain more on "document.title or a type selector."? I'm a complete noob.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding title and class:

- "title" - For any given HTML page, title is a single entity. One cannot have more than one title in a web page.
- "class" - Elements with the same class name, gives us the flexibility to have a common style for them.

Now, coming back to the question, since "title" element will not be repeated, it doesn't make sense to have a class attribute associated with it.

P.S: HTML will allow you to add the class attribute to the title element.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense to me. However, does it have a strong use with to 'allow it to be selected with JS '? As for example, if we had the same class attribute on titles across 1000 pages on a website. I'm a noob marketer trying understand code.

Comment: @KSokd - If you have some pages in which the title element has the class and some pages where the title element doesn't have the class, then you could use the same JS on all files that tests the title element for the presence of the class, and acts differently according to what it finds.

Comment: Thank you - I guess it would make sense to have it in this case then. Can it impact a website negatively to use it for this reason?